# Why does auto-attachment prioritize junk parts?

Tags: spaz2

Clicking auto-attach attachments to spine, especially when two or three attachment junk parts are available, prioritizes these over items with better stats (1-3 stars).

1. Is there a reason why the game tells you that using junk attachments is the better choice?
2. Does the auto-attach go for a balanced damage stats between shield, armor, health without consideration for parts synergy or quality?
3. I have seen my threat level decrease after having the game suggest attachments instead of my custom attachments. Is threat level just about your effective DPS or does it also include defensive stats in threat calculation?

Comment: Since the game is in beta, it is probably better to ask about it on the forums.  It could be a bug in the code when determining attachment priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a lot of experimentation, I think I can answer this question.

1. Oftentimes, a 3-attachment junk part might be better than three standalone parts because the 3-attachment part might offer similar damage while adding lower mass to the ship.
2. Auto-attach prioritizes utilizing nodes that have higher synergy bonus and puts the most effective part that can go on that node.
3. Threat level is based on the weapon damage of your nose / wings / engines. Sometimes, having non-damage bonuses (like increased maneuverability) might be deemed more important by the auto-attach algorithm. It will also make sure you don't have an excess of one damage-type and will try to balance between shield damage, hull damage and health damage.